# How to save repository using pip install git+?

Tags: python, git, pip

I install the package using pip3 install --user git+ssh://address , but I want to have this repo locally on my PC. Is it possible to do that? I need it because I need to retrieve hash of the last commit from this repo.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, when you install a package it _is_ now installed locally on your computer. In terms of getting the latest hash you would get that by reinstalling the package, unless using a private package manager `git` dot keep track of commits

Comment: "I want to have this repo locally on my PC" - so basically `git clone git://the.actual.repo`?

Comment: Ok lets assume, that I can use only pip3 install, and I want to know if there is a way to clone repo with with some extra parameter without git clone manually. Do you know any other solution for get last commit hash using pip? When I install package using pip it's installed but don't know what is the last commit hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install in [editable mode](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs). In this mode `pip` clones and preserves the repository in `src` directory in the root of your virtual environment. (You do use virtualenv, don't you?)

```
pip install -e `git+ssh://address#egg=module`
```

With option `--user` `pip` clones the repo into `./src` in whatever the current directory is.

Comment: What is "#egg=module" ?

Comment: See [Working Out the Name and Version for VCS packages](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#working-out-the-name-and-version).